# Strange order with redis list

Tags: redis

We used redis list in a Spring web application and used the lpush/rpop command and expected it to behave as a FIFO queue. But it wasn't! It pops a random element from the list. You can see that at the following lrange output.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> lrange word_getprice_queue:2520e2df-6771-4ee0-8cea-f6b2c68019b3 0 -1
 1) "ef682e35-aea8-4cb4-bd32-26b52d7943e0"
 2) "83f4ff87-0a8e-4631-8f2c-7785b298077b"
 3) "99fdb591-d2ed-4bef-b85e-38ee42dbe8ef"
 4) "9527ca7e-b6e7-4d7f-93c2-d3b59bb1aacc"
 5) "4ad6a66e-c727-4373-8e81-82e330adba92"
 6) "23f201b4-02c6-4385-9080-bd0a6b21bdc8"
 7) "3c9b6876-e3ba-481a-8012-f0b364830bfd"
 8) "0c00e8f6-5de4-4685-bee1-cec4eca4b546"
 9) "bb6b87b0-05e9-4a8b-9617-060f32963f68"
10) "1048e02f-0bbd-4130-b94e-ab658d77d7c6"

127.0.0.1:6379> lrange word_getprice_queue:2520e2df-6771-4ee0-8cea-f6b2c68019b3 0 -1
1) "3c9b6876-e3ba-481a-8012-f0b364830bfd"
2) "0c00e8f6-5de4-4685-bee1-cec4eca4b546"
3) "bb6b87b0-05e9-4a8b-9617-060f32963f68"
4) "1048e02f-0bbd-4130-b94e-ab658d77d7c6"
5) "ef682e35-aea8-4cb4-bd32-26b52d7943e0"
6) "83f4ff87-0a8e-4631-8f2c-7785b298077b"
7) "99fdb591-d2ed-4bef-b85e-38ee42dbe8ef"
8) "9527ca7e-b6e7-4d7f-93c2-d3b59bb1aacc"
9) "4ad6a66e-c727-4373-8e81-82e330adba92"

127.0.0.1:6379> lrange word_getprice_queue:2520e2df-6771-4ee0-8cea-f6b2c68019b3 0 -1
1) "bb6b87b0-05e9-4a8b-9617-060f32963f68"
2) "1048e02f-0bbd-4130-b94e-ab658d77d7c6"
3) "ef682e35-aea8-4cb4-bd32-26b52d7943e0"
4) "83f4ff87-0a8e-4631-8f2c-7785b298077b"
5) "99fdb591-d2ed-4bef-b85e-38ee42dbe8ef"
6) "9527ca7e-b6e7-4d7f-93c2-d3b59bb1aacc"
7) "3c9b6876-e3ba-481a-8012-f0b364830bfd"
8) "0c00e8f6-5de4-4685-bee1-cec4eca4b546"
```

I've updated the redis to 3.0.7 and jedis to 2.4.2 but has no luck.

[usages about the redis list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lar0.png)

TaskPusherGetPriceWord、TaskGet5Price、TaskPusherWordCount are three spring scheduled tasks. TaskPusherGetPriceWord push some words into the queue and TaskGet5Price pop those words from the queue and TaskPusherWordCount just empties the queue if something happens. You can see all the calls to manipulate the queue in the project from the above picture.

```
    <task:scheduled-tasks>
            <task:scheduled ref="taskPusherGetPriceWord" method="doTask" fixed-delay="300000" />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>

    <task:scheduled-tasks>
            <task:scheduled ref="taskGet5Price" method="doTask"     fixed-delay="5" />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>

    <task:scheduled-tasks>
            <task:scheduled ref="taskPusherWordCount" method="doTask"       fixed-delay="60000" />
    </task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Comment: Can you paste more of your code? Where are you using `lpush` and `rpop`? Are you doing any other operations? The fact that your order completely changes between lrange runs tells me there's something else weird going on.

Comment: Hi Eli, I just updated the post and you can see how we use the redis list. In fact, the order doesn't change totally.  Some elements move forward and others move back. They move by group but the order in the group remains unchanged.